# Model being picked up OK by controller but not by rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following through a simple tutorial and running into the following issue;

```
Task.create task: 'This is my task'
```

Returns an error when rspec tries to run it;

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   Could not find table 'tasks'
```

But when I call the exact same line from the rails console or from a controller the task is created and I am able to see the new row from within the rails console.

Initially I thought it was maybe something going weird with guard, because I have noticed a few odd things (Ctrl+C doesn't kill it for one) but I decided to run the test directly using rspec and it returns the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have you test db set up? try running `rake db:test:prepare` before running your tests.

Comment: That was exactly it - thanks so much. If you throw that comment into an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set up and prepare your db first and you can do that by running `rake db:test:prepare`